# Remap a counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following:

```
c = {('jack','jones'): 1, 
     ('jane','doe'): 2, 
     ('mike','jones'): 3, 
     ('jerry','doe'): 4,
     ('mary','jones'): 2}
```

how do I remap this dict so as to create the following dict, where the surname is used as the key instead of both first and last names:

```
{('jones',): 6, ('doe',): 6}
```

And where the values in the new dict are the sum of the values for that surname in the original dict.

Comment: @Rakesh Improved my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply loop over the items and keep adding the counts:

```
c = {('jack','jones'): 1, ('jane','doe'): 2, ('mike','jones'): 3, ('jerry','doe'): 4,('mary','jones'): 2}
c_new = {}
for k, v in c.items():
   c_new[k[1:]] = c_new.setdefault(k[1:], 0) + v

c_new
# {('doe',): 6, ('jones',): 6}
```